# Getting an SSRS map to include 0 in data

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I've been working a lot with maps in SSRS recently and can't seem to find a way to set a visualization to include a 0 value in the Field to Visualize area. Has anyone found a way to include 0 so the legend reflects nothing is in a certain area on the map layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I brought some props! It turns out if you look in the map layers in whichever layer you are setting, there's an option in the drop down called *yourLayer* Color Rule. [image] Once selected, If you click on distribution you can change the distribution options from 'Optimal' to 'Custom' and then select the ranges you want your legend and map to use. [image]

I hope this helps other SSRS users to get the visualization set properly.
Thanks to [William Weber](http://williamweber.net/formatting-map-legends-in-sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services/) for pointing me in the right direction.